# "Enable for inline editing" checkboxes, how is the end result achieved

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

I've been playing around the "Enable for inline editing" checkboxes on CT- and schema field level, and although they are performing their intended work I'm puzzled as how do they achieve this.

Here is my test scenario and dilemma:

- two schemas with a text field. The field is disabled for inline editing in the first schema and enabled in the second, marked S-1/0 below
- two CTs with enable and enable unchecked, marked CT-1/0 below. Both CTs are linked to both schemas

A test page containing all the combinations:

1) a component based on S0 with CT0

2) a component based on S0 with CT1

3) a component based on S1 with CT0

4) a component based on S1 with CT1

When I examine output from the CTs from Template Builder, they are exactly the same(apart from some IDs, etc.). So I said "OK, something must be happening when the content is published and not ran in TB or preview mode". After publishing I examined the output from the broker and yet again the same output...

When I publish my test page and edit it I get the correct behavior. Only combination S1+CT1 is editable.

Can someone please explain how do does XPM implement this functionality and where do the values of the checkboxes end up and how and when are they applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checkboxes have no effect on source code published to your preview environment. They are checked by the XPM editor before allowing users to edit those fields. This way, you can maintain a standardised way of outputting the required markup that does not need to check that the box is ticked and you can also control the 'edit-ability' of individual fields without needing to re-publish anything.

Answer (score 4):

These values are checked at run-time by Experience Manager. We've done it this way so that you can enable & disable it without having to republish all the content. The same principle applies for Templates btw.

Comment: 4 seconds faster... dammit! :D

Comment: Marked David's answer as the accepted, sorry Nuno, but he was indeed faster 4 seconds :P

Comment: Aha. That's totally fine :) as long as you got the answer you needed!

Comment: Actually, on my screen Nuno's answer seemed to be first - it's not an issue though - neither of us are competing for the points... Like he says, the important thing is that you got the answer you needed ;)